# Non-recursive traverse and Element implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to rewrite this [tiny function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28072418/is-it-possible-to-traverse-object-in-javascript-in-non-recursive-way) to TypeScript. Accessing `entry[key]` throws following ts error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'StringObjectOrArray'.
   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'StringObjectOrArray'.ts(7053)
```

It doesn't make sense to me. for .. in returns string index even on arrays which was new to me, but obviously integer as string can be natively used as array index. What am I missing?

```js
type StringKeyObject = { [key: string]: unknown };
type StringObjectOrArray = StringKeyObject | StringKeyObject[];

function traverse(obj: StringObjectOrArray) {
  if (!obj) {
    return;
  }

  const stack: [string, StringObjectOrArray][] = [['root', obj]];
  while (stack.length) {
    const [path, entry] = stack[0];
    for (const key in entry) {
      if (entry[key] && typeof entry[key] === "object") { // ts error here
        stack.push([`${path}.${key}`, entry[key]]);
      } else {
        console.log("%s: %s", `${path}.${key}`, entry[key]);
      }
    }
    stack.shift();
  }
}
```

Bellow is working JavaScript code:

```js
function traverse(obj) {
  if (!obj) {
    return;
  }

  const stack = [['root', obj]];
  while (stack.length) {
    const [path, entry] = stack[0];
    for (const key in entry) {
      if (entry[key] && typeof entry[key] === "object") {
        stack.push([`${path}.${key}`, entry[key]]);
      } else {
        console.log("%s: %s", `${path}.${key}`, entry[key]);
      }
    }
    stack.shift();
  }
}

traverse({
    one: "hello",
    two: "world",
    three: {
        one: 1,
        two: 2,
        three: 4,
        four: [{
            one: true,
            two: false
        }]
    },
    four: "!"
});
```

Comment: Try explicitly typing the return value or intermediate values with the type you expect, you may get a more illuminating error message.

Comment: @Ben Thanks. There is no return value. I just noticed that changing `StringKeyObject` to `{ [key: string | number]: unknown }` fixes that error, but as usual with typescript, I don't know why. I can't imagine how could possibly that case happen when typescript shows left hand of for loop natively typed as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, using a `for...in` loop on an array will cast the indexes to strings.

In Typescript, the `for...in` variable will always have type `string`, no matter what, and `number` is the [only index signature](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/89ab23a64941f7da4ca141fb9de89fcfeab7b7e5/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1476C12-L1476C12) for `Array`. So under normal circumstances, indexing the latter with the former is not allowed.

However, TS is capable of remembering that the `for...in` variable is cast from the index signature of the target of the loop. Inside the `for...in` loop, when you index an object with that variable, it will check the index signature. If and only if it (for a union, all members of the union) extends `number`, TS recognizes that the `for...in` index strings can/will be implicitly cast back into numbers if needed and allows it.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ssl=12&ssc=43&pln=12&pc=49#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCuBbAhgJ1TAXHJAjApqgNoC6MAvDKQNwBQoksCiIuAVljAN5EDWnzAqjLZBhAL4Vu4urQBmIDAAoG0GAEsNYHCnQBKbrRgxVsYAAt8wftigBPAA74QcjTHwAPKPjAATCDDQqOpgAOYwAPwwAIwC+ABuhFLRdMbMaMTqJKkm4Go2gVDBYVIARAAMpTnp6HzZMAD0DTAAciBORjqsbERZ1I3NACIg+BBgAOSw5siJMFAgWr6ec5Yw3Sv4i8vqAXKoIIi04rT0ebDwYOrgAniEpDAAPtxUvPh22EEh4U9iwqK3GEklHuyACyDAdjoCmUpjcIRgFyuYAMXE6NUy9SaMDkIU2RxOQA)

**Why doesn't TS see that `key` is `keyof object?`**

The type system just doesn't account for relationships between variables like that. `keyof` forms a unique type from the index signature of another type, but there's no association between them. TS knows the `for...in` variable is something like `keyof object` cast to `string`, but it doesn't actually keep track of the fact that you're literally iterating through the object's properties.

When indexing types with simple index signatures, that doesn't matter at all because the `keyof` type is identical to the index signature. With unions, however, it *does* matter because `keyof` a union is itself a union. For example, given a union `T = A | B` and `keyof T = keyof (A | B)`, you cannot guarantee from an abstract type perspective that any given `key : keyof T` indexes any given `object : T` because your `object` might be a `B` and `key` might be a `keyof A` or vice versa.

In your case, `StringObjectOrArray[keyof StringObjectOrArray]` is invalid because `keyof StringObjectOrArray` could be `keyof StringKeyObject[]` (`number`) and `StringObjectOrArray` could be `{[k : string] : unknown}`. The vice versa doesn't make a difference in this case because `keyof { [k : string] : ?}` is always `string | number` (It's confusing, I know, but [there's a reason](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types). I wasn't even aware of this until now.) and it just kinda gets subsumed by the union with `number[]` in `keyof StringObjectOrArray`.

Comment: Thank you for nice clarification. I understand what you say, but I don't understand purpose of that check. Since you iterate keys/indexes of native javascript object, TS shouldn't care about casting because that key itself is clearly keyof that object. From my perspective actually only string keys are allowed on that type of object and basically that union causes that I loose proper type check.

Comment: @bigless I updated my answer with an elaboration. Thank you for the great questions.

Comment: Thanks. I've figured out how to bypass this issue. By using Object.entries instead of for ... in.